# I'm trying to create an arrayList that could accept both integers and array

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

How do I create a generic array list in Java that could accept both integers and array?

```
[123,[],112,[],10]
```

Comment: Just create your object and add the arrays and integers... What is the problem?

Comment: another easy way would be to treat an int as a list with one element. that way, you can have a list of lists

Comment: Can you give us some indication of why you need this? While you can just use an `ArrayList<Object>` it probably indicates a design smell.

Answer (score 3):

Both int (Integer wrapper) and array's common base class is Object. So create [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) using Object type.

```
ArrayList<Object> list= new ArrayList<Object>();
```

But this is **not the right way** to solve this problem and there is no use of Generics here to make run-time safety. So, re-design your program and allocate each type in seperate list or use any other appropriate [Collection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/intro/) type.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the fastest way might be create an auxiliar object that is composed by boths Integers and array letting you to use boths by equal

Comment: it would be really helpful if you add some code which explain your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use a class which has an `int` and an array as its instance variables. Then create an `ArrayList` like

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Hello {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        ArrayList<Intarray> myArrayList = new ArrayList<Intarray>();

        int[] arr = {3,4,5};

        myArrayList.add(new Intarray(2,arr));
    }
}

class Intarray {
    private int numbers;
    private int[] myArray;

    public Intarray(int numbers, int[] myArray){
        this.numbers = numbers;
        this.myArray = myArray;
    }
}
```

Comment: While this a good way to achieve the desired results; this requires both an integer and an array, I belive the poster wanted either or... not both.

Answer (score 0):

Create the array list at the Generalization level for all the objects you need in the List. In this case,i.e for int and array, it is java.lang.Object.

Here's a small test I ran:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Object> both = new ArrayList<Object>();
    both.add(1);
    both.add(args);
    System.out.println(both);
}
```

Produces:
[1, [Ljava.lang.String;@1db9742]

Answer (score 0):

As @AbtPst suggested, the most suitable solution would be to have a list of lists. This can be done in many different ways. Personally, I'd create a class with two constructors.

```
class NumericElement
{
    private ArrayList<int> elements;

    public NumericElement(int newElement)
    {
        elements = new ArrayList<int>();
        elements.add(newElement);
    }

    public NumericElement(ArrayList<int> newElements)
    {
        elements = new ArrayList<int>(newElements); // copying array elements to the new array.
    }

    public ArrayList<int> getElements()
    {
        return elements;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a `List` class with a **type-safe interface**, hiding an unsafe `List<Object>` as an internal implementation detail.

This is more work than just using a `List<Object>` directly. If your list is used only by one class, just use a `List<Object>`, as an implementation detail of that one class. **But if your list is exposed to access by more than just one class, consider using this type-safe approach.**

First, define an interface that can represent either an int or a array of ints.

```
public interface IScalarOrArrayInt { }
```

And define a sub-interface for each possible element type:

```
public interface IScalarInt extends IScalarOrArrayInt { 
    public int getScalarInt();
}

public interface IArrayInt extends IScalarOrArrayInt {
    public int[] getIntArray();
}
```

Then define your list class and its representation. It's interface can be a `List<IScalarOrArrayInt>`. **The representation can be a `List<Object>`, so that you can put Integer and int[] objects into it directly, without wrapper objects.**

```
public class ListOfScalarsAndArray extends AbstractList<IScalarOrArrayInt> {
    private static List<Object> m_list = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

As noted in the `AbstractList` documentation, you'll want to define several methods to allow modifying your list. You can delegate them to the internal list, but wrap the return values.

```
@Override
public void add(int index, IScalarOrArrayInt element) {
    m_list.add( index, element );
}

@Override
public IScalarOrArrayInt remove(int index) {
    return wrap( m_list.remove( index ));
}

@Override
public IScalarOrArrayInt set(int index, IScalarOrArrayInt element) {
    return wrap( m_list.set( index, element ));
}
```

For the convenience of callers, you can add some methods that accept an unwrapped `int` or `int[]`. For example:

```
public void add( int element ) {
    m_list.add( element );
}

public void add( int[] element ) {
    m_list.add( element );
}
```

To satisfy the standard List<> interface, you can wrap return values. Your class controls the internal list, so it alone controls the possible types of list members.

```
private IScalarOrArrayInt wrap( Object o ) {
    if ( o instanceof Integer ) {
        final int i = (Integer) o;
        return new IScalarInt() {

            @Override
            public int getScalarInt() {
                return i;
            }
        };
    }
    else {
        assert( o instanceof int[] );

        final int[] a = (int[]) o;

        return new IArrayInt() {
            @Override
            public int[] getIntArray() {
                return a;
            }
        };
    }
}
```